# JavaScript: How can I assign a variable the same as another variable inside the same object?

Tags: javascript

sorry if this is a duplicate, but I couldn't find any others.

So I tried doing this.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");    

var player1 = {
    width: 20,
    height: 75,
    x: canvas.width/6-player1.width/2,
    y: canvas.height/2-player1.height/2,
    speed: 5
};

function drawPlayer1() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(player1.x, player1.y, player1.width, player1.height);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#b10000";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
}

drawPlayer1();
```

But the problem is that I can't assign `x` to `player1.width` because `width` is assigned inside `player1` where it's getting "used".

BTW I am doing this because of symmetry.

I could just have these variables for themselves, but I am trying to clean up my code.

So, how can I get around this problem by using objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `player1.width` is not defined yet-- because you are still in the middle of defining `player1`-- you can define it and the other static properties first, and then assign the dynamic ones on the next line with [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

```
var player1 = {
    width: 20,
    height: 75,
    speed: 5
};
Object.assign(player1, {
    x: canvas.width/6-player1.width/2,
    y: canvas.height/2-player1.height/2,
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Consider using [getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get).

```js
var player1 = {
  width: 20,
  height: 75,
  get x() { return this.width + 10 },
  get y() { return this.height + 10 }
};

console.log(player1.x, player1.y);
```

If you want the ability to set the value directly and override the formula, you could utilize [setters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set) too:

```js
var player1 = {
  width: 20,
  height: 75,
  _x: null,
  _y: null,

  get x() { return this._x || this.width + 10 },
  set x (newX) { this._x = newX },

  get y() { return this._y || this.height + 10 },
  set y (newY) { this._y = newY }
};

console.log(player1.x, player1.y);
player1.x = 500;
player1.y = 200;
console.log(player1.x, player1.y);
```

Comment: I don't think that's what they're going for if x and y changes.

Comment: @JacqueGoupil You may be right. If OP is trying to preserve the ability to set `x` directly, that might make this a bit more intricate. I'll add an additional piece of code to account for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access `player1` from within the definition of `player1` because it doesn't exist yet. When the interpreter parses this code, it first creates an object out of the object literal, then it stores it in the `player1` variable. And since `player1` didn't exist beforehand, `player1.width` causes an error.

```
// original code which doesn't work
var player1 = {
    width: 20,
    height: 75,
    x: canvas.width/6-player1.width/2,
    y: canvas.height/2-player1.height/2,
    speed: 5
};
```

A simple way to fix it is to set those variables after creating the object.

```
var player1 = { ... };

player1.x = canvas.width/6 - player1.width/2;
player1.y = canvas.height/2 - player1.height/2;
```

Alternatively you could do this:

```
Object.assign(player1, {
    x: canvas.width/6 - player1.width/2,
    y: canvas.height/2 - player1.height/2;
});
```

This code creates a new object with the x and y properties and then copies them to `player1`. But for just these two properties, I'd stick to the first solution, it's clearer and simpler.